# Function in R to get variable assignment coding?

Tags: r, variable-assignment

Assume I have object `foo`:

```
foo <- 2:12
```

I want to be able to call the object `foo` in a way that shows the original assignment syntax. For example:

```
>function(foo)
  2:12
```

Methods that don't work:

```
> paste0(foo)
 [1] "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12"
> quote(foo)
 foo
```

How do I appropriately do this?

**Update:** (for context):

My goal is to supply a range of values as an argument in a function, but that range needs to be applied as written (not drawn out).

---

Here is an example trying to simplify the issue that necessitated me asking this question. (This is a simplified version of my issue, so I understand that there are simple solutions to this specific case). I found a workaround to make the code work (see lines 25-26).

```
func1 <- function(gps,num) { 
  v <- NULL
  for(i in gps) {
    v <- c(v,num^i)
  }
  v
}

func2 <- function(dim,num) { 
  v <- cbind(rep(num,5))
  dim(v)[dim]
}

num.A <- 1
num.B <- 2
num.C <- 3

nums <- objects()[grep('num.',objects())]

gen.func <- function(func,num,other) {
  y <- gsub('num.','',num)
  args <- formalArgs(func)
  args2 <- args
  args2[grep('num',args)] <- paste0(args2[grep('num',args)],'.',y)
  args2[grep('num',args,invert = T)] <- 'x'
  x <<- other
  lst <- mget(c(args2),envir = parent.frame())
  names(lst) <- formalArgs(func)
  do.call(func,lst)
}

gen.func(func1,nums[1],other = 2:12)
gen.func(func2,nums[1],other = 2)
```

Comment: I prefer base R solutions if possible. I fulyl welcome other methods, but please provide a base R solution, too, if possible :).

Comment: I welcome the addition of any additional appropriate tags for this questions, too. Thanks!

Comment: 2:12 is a sequence from 2 to 12.  Perhaps `as.list(substitute(foo <- 2:12))[[3]]#2:12`

Comment: @akrun yes I understand. I guess what I want is a function that returns `2:12` as a string. Or, using another example, if I had `foo <- mean(1:5)` I would want my function to return the string `mean(1:5)` instead of `3`.

Comment: Please check the edited comment above it gives the output 2:12 Or use it as a function `f1 <- function(expr){
     tail(as.list(substitute(expr)),1)[[1]]
 };
 f1(foo <- 2:12)
#2:12`

Comment: In general R doesn't save any information about how objects were created, so what you're asking is not possible.

The exception to this general rule is that when you create a function, it *does* record information about how it was created.

Comment: @akrun thanks, but that approach won't work for me. To provide context: I want to provide a range of values to an argument in a function. Within that function, the range needs to be applied as text (instead of 1,2,3,4....)

Comment: Based on the two examples you provided earlier, the `f1` works.  If you are thinking about something else, then it should be the example in the post

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. Describe better the context and your problem. It's very unlikely that the original definition of an object might be necessary to solve a problem.

Comment: Your description is still vague. I don't get what you mean by "written" and "drawn out". Make a specific example.

Comment: @nicola working on it....

Comment: You really need to explain what that code in `gen.func` does because it uses so many odd tricks of R that it's practically opaque.

Comment: maybe that example and explaining would be too complicated and not worth anybody's time. What If I just explained what I'm trying to do...

Comment: I have many functions that I want to apply to various objects *individually* (with each object being named "name.x", "name.y", etc.). I wanted to write a generic function that would take each object individually and pair it up with one of numerous functions that use mostly the same inputs. I can do so quickly because the arguments for each function are some simplified variation of the object names I'm providing. However, I have 1 argument in each function that is unique to that function that I want to account for. I'm trying to insert a general argument ("other") to account for these.

Comment: However, sometimes this argument in a given function takes a string of arguments (e.g., 2:12)

Comment: You refer to lines 25-26, but fyi, lines are not numbered in display here.

Comment: @Frank I know. But giving specific line numbers when counting to a low number like 25 is fairly quick and  is easier than referencing the code itself (which could become ambiguous).

Comment: But a comment in the code like `# workaround below` is much clearer and also robust to future edits.

Answer (score 8):

R doesn’t store this information in any way, so it cannot be retrieved. In order to store it, you’d need to override `<-` in a nontrivial way:

```
`<-` = function (lhs, rhs) {
    lhs = substitute(lhs)
    assign_expr = bquote({
        assign(.(deparse(lhs, backtick = TRUE)), .(rhs))
        attr(.(lhs), 'repr') = substitute(.(substitute(rhs)))
    })
    eval.parent(assign_expr)
}
```

Then you can use:

```
> x <- 1 : 5

> x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
attr(,"repr")
1:5

> attr(x, 'repr')
1:5
```

Comment: While this is clever, I wouldn't suggest anybody in the world to use it.

Comment: @nicola Totally agreed. It may be useful for non-standard usage though (e.g. debugging).

Comment: @theforestecologist It’s part of `bquote`’s syntax. [You can read up about it in the — admittedly poor — documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bquote.html). Like I said, this is nontrivial, and explaining `bquote` is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: @theforestecologist loosely, `.(x)` indicates replace `x` with whatever is contained inside `x` in the calling environment, where `bquote()` is creating an expression: basically don't include `lhs` *literally* in the expression, but do include what `lhs` represents.